# What is a key hash?Why it is needed?Is it unique?Why it is necessary for facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, integration

What is a key-hash, why it is needed and is it unique? Also why it is necessary for facebook integration?

My code to get the `HashKey`:

```
try{
   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.packagename", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
   for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
       MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
       md.update(signature.toByteArray());
       Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
   }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: simply for security so it would be unique...

Comment: It's unique. It identifies your app in Facebook developer platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is key Hash?**

It's a  `28 character` string that `Facebook` uses to authenticate interactions between your `app` and the `Facebook`.

**Why it is Unique?**

As already mentioned in comments, It identifies your `app` in `Facebook` developer platform.

**Why it is needed? Why it is necessary for Facebook Integration?**

It is needed to authenticate the exchange of information between your `app` and the `Facebook`. Without this, your `Facebook` integration may not work properly when you release your app to the store. If you run apps that use Facebook Login then you need to add your Android development key hash to your Facebook developer profile.

Answer (score 0):

For integrating your app with facebook API you will need this key. Log KeyHash will give you value which you will have to write in facebook app's setting page.
than only your application with given SHA1 code will able to access facebook api. Or you'll get authorization error. P.S: It will be unique and different for all apps and testing device and even workspace.

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\manish.Manish-PC\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64   This asks for a password when i type android i get a hash key and if i type some thing else i get a different key. Please help why this happens and how the key differentiate or in which scenario it is unique

Comment: this is command for getting keystore... same thing will be done with your given function

Comment: When i type android as a password i get a key and i type something else i get different hash key

Comment: it will give correct one if you write android as password... others wont work

Comment: I am new to Integration i don't know what all things are needed for this please help me !!! How to initiate and what are the the necessary things for intergration

Comment: avoid making it with cmd... do it in your app,let say in splash... than in facebook app page in setting there will be field like App name, App secret, Sha1, keyhashes/keystore. Put all values accordingly... than you may run your app with fb integration.

Comment: you can also download sample project and follow it

Comment: Not getting SHA 1 option there